# A question on orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, orthogonal-matrices

Let $P\in R^{n\times n}$ be an  orthogonal matrix. I want to ask whether or not there exists some vector $x\in R^n$ containing no zero entries such that $Px$ also contains no zero entries.

Comment: yes : the set of vectors with no zero entry is an open in Zariski topology, so is its images by P, and it preimage by P, so the intersection of these three sets is open, and since $\mathbf R$ is infinite, is non-empty.

Comment: True but more advanced than necessary, and also hiding the key point that 
$P$, being orthogonal, is invertible.  Hence the set of $x$ such that 
$x$ or $Px$ **does** have at least one zero entry is the union of $2n$ subspaces 
of positive codimension.   This can't be all of ${\bf R}^n$ because $\bf R$ 
is infinite.  
(For example, any hyperplane intersects the "rational normal curve" 
$\{(1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^{n-1})\}$ in fewer than $n$ points.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of Zariski topology consider usual topology. Every open ball will contain a vector with all entries non-zero. (I leave this to you to verify).
As $P$ is invertible it is a homeomorphism. Image of open ball will contain  open ball. QED